# Avoid large classes for interface implementation

Tags: java, interface, refactoring

I have always tried to follow the advise by Mr. Martin and others of keeping my classes small. Very small, having only one reason to change a class. But now I am facing a dilemma where I do not think this will be that convenient.

I have an interface for `GenericDatabase`s. This interface defines all methods that any implementation has to implement (e.g. `getUsers`, `getUser(id)`, etc), perhaps 30 or 40 of them.

This way is very convenient, since a class only has to implement that interface and the code will work seamless with different specific databases. However, the problem is that such implementations can get +7000 lines long (god class).

What I have normally done in the past, is to divide the database functionality in different classes according to the objects they managed. But it was only for one fixed database implementation. Now, I could divide the functionality into different interfaces according to the database objects (users, documents, etc) but then it seems more burden to maintain. First, I cannot assure that a database implementation implements all interfaces. Then, developers are required to create perhaps 20 different classes implementing 20 different interfaces, where before everything could be found in a single class implementing a single interface. So I am not sure if this is an exception to the rule of always keep your classes small.

How can this class/design be refactored?

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you're assuming there's a database at all. I'd expect a `UserService` to return information about users, and I'd use a library that abstracts the actual database away when there is a db (such as Hibernate, spring-data, etc.). Why should I write code that has already been written?

Comment: Because the application needs to get data from a data source. Some people will need to retrieve the data from their MySQL database. Others, from their MongoDB. Others, from a file.... But the application has to work for all of them seamlessly. The way to guarantee this, is by a contract (Java interface). `UserService` will have to implement the interface. But also `DocumentService`, `UserInstitutionService`, etc So this is the 2nd situation I described

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you saying that you want a generic system that allows you to store **any** kind of data in **any** kind of datasource? [Don't do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: Nop. I want a system that shows specific data (defined in a Java interface) for any kind of datasource (as long as they implement the interface, I do not care what is underneath)

Comment: Yes, which is what I said in my last comment. You're not the first or the last one to try for that, but luckily I was here to tell you that it's a stupid idea and it will never work, and I even gave you an informative link. You can of course ignore my advice. In fact I hope you ignore my advice, so you can learn the lesson yourself. Lessons are good, they teach you things.

Comment: I completely disagree. I have made a system in the past with this "large class" in place, and the same visual application could be used by 5 different places that store the same sort of information in different databases. So I do not think the idea is stupid or will not work. It is necessary for me and it works. I am only facing the dilemma of maintenance of large classes with Java interfaces. If you do not want to see the "database" example, think of the interface "Figure" where you define "paint", "describe" and 200 more methods. Now your clients have "Circle", "Squares" and "Triangles"....

Comment: The fact that you've created a `GenericDatabase` interface just tells me that you've done a lot of work for nothing. You don't do that unless you're writing a JDBC driver or something similar. A different database isn't a problem, just use JPA or spring-data, like I said. You don't write that kind of code yourself in 2018.

Comment: I think you are not getting my question...It is about *refactoring large classes when an interface has a lot of methods*. But moving to what ure questioning:Your 10 clients get to you saying they need a single user interface for their DIFFERENT data sources with SIMILAR data. They could create the connector, since they know their own data. What do u do? Create 10 different applications according to datasource? Or create only 1 with the interface they need to implement so everything works as long as they comply? Spring/etc cannot work with some of the (propietary) datasources that they have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164321/discussion-between-user1156544-and-kayaman).

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Comment: It did not give me the full answer (perhaps I need to elaborate more) but it can be considered a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind, the ground rule is: you always prefer a **complex** network of **simple** things over a **simple** network of complex things.

The point is: as soon as interfaces (and therefore implementing classes) get too large, they (almost automatically) violate the Single Responsibility Principle. And sooner or later (rather: sooner) that means that instead of small, "understandable" units you end up with those large classes that are simply "too large".

Again: the *main* motivation for preferring smaller classes is the fact that your brain is much better at understanding "the whole thing"  when that "whole thing" is small enough to "fit" into your brain.

So, yes - that might mean that you come up with a series of interfaces. And more classes implementing them. Complexity is like water: you can't compress it - you can only choose how it "flows".

Beyond that, Domain Driven Design might have some good advise here as well - for example regarding the fact that not all methods belong on an **Entity** - sometimes it makes much more sense to have **Service** classes that are responsible for "doing something" with an entity (instead of having the entity implement that method itself).

Given the comment by the OP: one has to understand that it is *hard* to give specific advice on such "generic" input. In order to really come up with *helpful* interfaces (that make more sense on their own, enough sense to "make up" for the *cost* of having many interfaces) one has to sit down and see the *real* requirements. Meaning: it is not possible to give more specific advice at this point. This is something that can only be resolved by the OP (and his peer) sitting together and carefully making experiments to figure which design options best fits their needs.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer/comment so far. I am still not quite convince that the multiple interfaces will be easier to maintain. So far I know that everything related to the data I need is in that class, rather than delegating it to multiple Entity or Service classes that get that specific information from the data source

Comment: @user1156544 You are welcome. Please see the last paragraph I just added to my answer - I feat there isnt too much else I can say here.

Comment: @user1156544 reading your comments to my comments in our chat, you haven't given enough information about your actual use case. You do on the other hand seem to have a negative approach to the whole thing, especially considering your "Python is better" comment. I (and I imagine GhostCat) based my question on best practices and my own experience. You're seeing flaws in your current approach, but you're also reluctant to let go of it. Edit your question and include a description of your *business problem* instead of the way you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, but I opened the chat with you for a reason. I don't think you are understanding my problem and I found your answers not very related. I am not seeing any flaws in my approach (I know it has advantages and disadv. that's why I open this question). The thing with Python... OK : ) Never said "better", I just said that no wonder why other people complain about Java being overbloated (I don't program in Python) when there are a lot of classes that abstract other classes that call a connector that finally calls a real implementation. Sometimes for systems that never change. Anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your class small is just a recipe to try to avoid giving more than one responsibility to a class. The problem I see is that your interface is trying to do too many things.

If you are working with a separate layer for the bussiness I suggest you look into the [Repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Every concept of the model has a small number of methods he cares for and that is the interface he is linked to. Each interface could have one or more implementations that are not so big. Maybe, some of them could inherit or cooperate with a Database Helper that has little responsibility (create a connection, create a prepared statement and little more).

Comment: As far as I understood, the repository is like the layer I am trying to model in the interface, isnt it?  So if the interface is trying to do too many things, then you think it is better the 2nd option -dividing the interface in many? Because that is what I am questioning, if maintenance of all these elements would be easier. And also, how to guarantee that they are all implemented

Comment: Not exactly. You don't need to guarantee that they are implemented. The repository works with domain object. In your example, you could have a repository for User with basic operations over User and another repository for Page. This repositories are interfaces and they could have more than one implementation. Your question is how to make sure they are working with the same kind of implementation? Well, you don't. Use the kind of dependency injection to provide the right implementation that could be all Postgre, or Postgre to users and sqlite to pages.